# missing session data after ajax request

Tags: php

I have 3 page my problem is missing session data after Ajax request,  I have a simple form like below code when I don't  click button1, and submit form  my code works fine and I can get session values in pages3 but If  click button1 and request Ajax , session data is missing in page3 please help what I do?
Thanks

page1.php code

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['firstname']) ){
      $_SESSION['firstname']= $_POST['firstname'];
  } 
  if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
      $_SESSION['lastname']= $_POST['lastname'];
  } 
?>
<form id="form1" action="page3.php">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text"  id="firstname" name="firstname" value="">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="save">
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button1').on("click",function(){

        jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               data:  $('#form1').serialize(),
               url:page2.php,
               dataType   : 'json', 
               encode    : true,
               success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
              }
        }); 
    }); 
 });
</script>
```

page2.php code

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

    //some code here
?>
```

page3.php code

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $firstname=$_SESSION['firstname'];
   $lastname=$_SESSION['lastname'];

    //some code here
 ?>
```

Comment: when you are doing through jquery then you have to write this into page2.php:-`if(isset($_POST['firstname']) ){
                 $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
                 $_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname;
                } 

                if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
                 $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
                 $_SESSION['lastname']=  $lastname;
                } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you are doing it through jquery, your `page1` is not refreshed and that's why `SESSION` saving code on the upside of the page is not executing and you are not getting values on other pages.

Solution:-

In case of ajax on `page2.php` write like below (remove it from `page1`):-

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) ){ 
  $firstname=$_POST['firstname']; 
  $_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname; 
} if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){ 
  $lastname=$_POST['lastname']; 
  $_SESSION['lastname']= $lastname; 
}
```

In case of using form `POST` everything worked fine,because the code on top of `page1` will execute.

***But the correct thing in this case also is remove code on top of the `page1` and put it on `page3.php` (same code what i have stated above)***